# How do I? request single character "y" or "n" instead of multibyte answer in multi-lingual environment?

Tags: install4j

I'm using Install4j 5.0.x

I want to make multi-lingual environment support product(English, Chinese(Simplified)).

In RedHat Linux with Chinese(Simplified) input method, During installing, a specified question request to answer multi-byte word.

Here is screen shot.
http://blog.naver.com/mopsld
How can I request "y" or "n" instead of multi-byte word ?